# ¿Como llenar un Datatable Session con datos temporales?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Mi problema es que tengo que guardar datos temporales de un usuario, aunque ya intente con una variable de session no se guardan, solo se queda con la ultima informacion ingresada

```
DataTable datos = new DataTable();

                datos.Columns.Add("Numero de guia", typeof(string));
                datos.Columns.Add("Estado del paquete", typeof(string));
                datos.Columns.Add("Estacion", typeof(string));
                datos.Columns.Add("Modulo", typeof(string));
datos.Rows.Add(new object[] { (Convert.ToString(Session["Numeroguia"])), condicion, estacion.est_nombre, objmuestra.mod_referencia });
```

Y necesito que el datatable tenga las filas que haya ingresado el usuario ya sea una o 20
De antemano gracias.

Answer (score 1):

El concepto es crear un DataTable dinámico, almacenar algunos valores en él y luego mantener el DataTable en ViewState o Session, dependiendo de si lo desea solo en la página o en toda la aplicación, respectivamente.

Te explicaré cómo usar un DataTable como una tabla de almacenamiento temporal en ASP.Net para almacenar los registros que necesitamos para procesar en ViewState o variables de sesión.

Para ilustrar este concepto, haré uso de un control ASP.Net GridView en el que realizaré operaciones de edición y actualización y guardaré los datos actualizados con el DataTable temporal.

El siguiente marcado HTML consta de ASP.Net GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowEditing="OnRowEditing">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Country" HeaderText="Country" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton Text="Edit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" />
        </ItemTemplate>
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton Text="Update" runat="server" OnClick="OnUpdate" />
            <asp:LinkButton Text="Cancel" runat="server" OnClick="OnCancel" />
        </EditItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

### Namespaces

Necesitarás importar el siguiente namespace:

### C#

```
using System.Data;
```

### Visual Basic

```
Imports System.Data
```

Poblando GridView con un DataTable temporal dinámico dentro del controlador de eventos Page Load de la página, primero estoy creando un objeto DataTable temporal dinámico, agregando columnas y luego agregando algunos datos a DataTable.

Luego, esta DataTable temporal dinámica se guarda en una variable ViewState y finalmente se usa para completar el control GridView.

### C#

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("Id"), new DataColumn("Name"), new DataColumn("Country") });
        dt.Rows.Add(1, "John Hammond", "United States");
        dt.Rows.Add(2, "Mudassar Khan", "India");
        dt.Rows.Add(3, "Suzanne Mathews", "France");
        dt.Rows.Add(4, "Robert Schidner", "Russia");
        ViewState["dt"] = dt;
        this.BindGrid();
    }
}
 
protected void BindGrid()
{
    GridView1.DataSource = ViewState["dt"] as DataTable;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

### Visual Basic

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("Id"), new DataColumn("Name"), new DataColumn("Country") });
        dt.Rows.Add(1, "John Hammond", "United States");
        dt.Rows.Add(2, "Mudassar Khan", "India");
        dt.Rows.Add(3, "Suzanne Mathews", "France");
        dt.Rows.Add(4, "Robert Schidner", "Russia");
        ViewState["dt"] = dt;
        this.BindGrid();
    }
}
 
protected void BindGrid()
{
    GridView1.DataSource = ViewState["dt"] as DataTable;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

| Nombre | País |
| --- | --- |
| John Hammond | Estados Unidos |
| Mudassar Khan | India |
| Suzanne Mathews | Francia |
| Robert Schidner | Rusia |

### Controlador de eventos OnRowEditing

A continuación se muestra el controlador de eventos OnRowEditing que se activará para una fila GridView cuando se haga clic en el botón de edición dentro de esa fila.

Dentro de este controlador de eventos, estoy configurando GridView EditIndex con NewEditIndex obtenido del objeto GridViewEditEventArgs y luego GridView se completa nuevamente desde el DataTable temporal almacenado dentro de la variable ViewState.
El proceso anterior establece GridView en modo de edición.

### C#

```
OnRowEditing vacío protegido ( remitente del objeto , GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    este .BindGrid ();
}
```

### Visual Basic

```
Protected Sub OnRowEditing (remitente como objeto , e como GridViewEditEventArgs )
    GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex
    Yo .BindGrid ()
End Sub
```

| Nombre | País |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| John Hammond | Estados Unidos | actualizar cancelar |
| Mudassar Khan | India | editar |
| Suzanne Mathews | Francia | editar |
| Robert Schidner | Rusia | editar |

Actualizar filas de GridView y cancelar eventos de edición
A continuación se muestran los controladores de eventos para los botones Actualizar y Cancelar.
Dentro del controlador de eventos Update, el DataTable temporal se recupera de la variable ViewState y luego la fila que se actualizará se identifica mediante el RowIndex de GridView Row en cuyo botón Actualizar se hizo clic.

Luego, los valores que se actualizarán se obtienen de los TextBoxes y se asignan a las columnas respectivas de la fila DataTable.

Finalmente, el DataTable temporal se guarda nuevamente en ViewState y el GridView se llena nuevamente con el DataTable temporal actualizado.

Dentro del controlador de eventos Cancel, GridView EditIndex se establece en -1 y GridView se completa con datos del DataTable temporal guardado en ViewState.

### C#

```
OnUpdate vacío protegido ( remitente de objeto , EventArgs e)
{
    Fila de GridViewRow = (remitente como LinkButton ) .NamingContainer como GridViewRow ;
    string name = (row.Cells [0] .Controls [0] as TextBox ) .Text;
    string country = (row.Cells [1] .Controls [0] as TextBox ) .Text;
    DataTable dt = ViewState [ "dt" ] como DataTable ;
    dt.Rows [row.RowIndex] [ "Nombre" ] = nombre;
    dt.Rows [row.RowIndex] [ "País" ] = país;
    ViewState [ "dt" ] = dt;
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    este .BindGrid ();
}
 
OnCancel vacío protegido ( remitente de objeto , EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
    este .BindGrid ();
}
```

### Visual Basic

```
Sub protegido OnUpdate (remitente como objeto , e como EventArgs )
    Atenuar fila como GridViewRow = TryCast ( TryCast (remitente, LinkButton ) .NamingContainer, GridViewRow )
    Dim name As String = TryCast (row.Cells (0) .Controls (0), TextBox ) .Text
    Dim country As String = TryCast (row.Cells (1) .Controls (0), TextBox ) .Text
    Dim dt As DataTable = TryCast (ViewState ( "dt" ), DataTable )
    dt.Rows (row.RowIndex) ( "Nombre" ) = nombre
    dt.Rows (row.RowIndex) ( "País" ) = país
    ViewState ( "dt" ) = dt
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1
    Yo .BindGrid ()
End Sub
 
Sub OnCancel protegido (remitente como objeto , e como EventArgs )
    GridView1.EditIndex = -1
    Yo .BindGrid ()
End Sub
```